# Cannot send email through Office 365 using SMTP server (MFA is off)

Tags: c#, email, smtp, office365, microsoft365

A client of mine recently changed IT providers, and in doing so, recreated their Office 365 setup (including Sharepoint and Outlook).

When they did this, they turned on MFA (multi-factor authentication) as default. In doing this, it seems they have somehow blocked my application from sending emails through the SMTP server under their users.

Here is the basic sample of my code

```
using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("Smtp.office365.com", 587))
{
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user@domain.com", "password");

    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage()
    {
        From = new MailAddress("user@domain.com"),
        IsBodyHtml = false,
        Subject = "Test message",
        Body = "Test content",
    };

    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("receiver@domain.com"));
    client.Send(mail);
};
```

When I send an email I receive the following error -

System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 'The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 Client not authenticated to send mail.

So at first I was unable to send due to MFA being turned ON, but now I don't think that's the problem anymore, we've tried a lot of stuff, and I still can't get an email to send.

I can log in to the account using the username/password I've been given, so I don't believe it's a true authentication problem.

Here's what we've tried:

- Enabling SMTP auth
- App passwords instead of user password to circumvent the MFA in the app.
- Disabling MFA on this particular user.
- Switching this account from a shared mailbox to a regular mailbox.
- Disabling Azure Security Defaults.

I don't know what else to look at. The error doesn't seem to be pointing to anything obvious. Can someone please help.

(Also, for the record, I know there's other questions like this, but none have solved the problem, so here we are).

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?